# Delete query not working due to old mysql version

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, crud

I have written the following query to delete 100 rows only:

```
delete T1 from table1 T1
INNER table2 T2 ON
T1.column1 = T2.column1
where T2.id IN(select id from table2 where date >= '2001-01-01' limit 100)
```

I am getting an error
`This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of in you can use join 
`delete T1 from table1 T1
INNER table2 T2 ON
T1.column1 = T2.column1 
JOIN (select id from table2 where date >= '2001-01-01' limit 100) AS temp
On temp.id =T2.id`